# What is the name of a data structure hidden from the user?

Tags: c, terminology

Suppose a .h file provides "struct user_object;", but does not specify its members, or how big it is.  What is that called?  I am thinking Abstract Data Type, but that is something else...  Can't find it anywhere...

Comment: [Pimpl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)?  [Handle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_%28computing%29)?

Comment: Maybe opaque type?

Comment: Usually called "opaque data type" in C: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type

Comment: Sorry-- I had no internet access over the weekend, to accept the answer earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard uses the term "incomplete" to describe those types. But the terminology really depends on what you want to use it for. "Incomplete" is meaningful when talking about what your code can do with a struct like that, but often "opaque" is used when describing intent (which in this case would be that the author doesn't want the users to touch what's inside).

Comment: "Opaque" is what I was looking for.